# How to serve JSON payload in the initial request, for use in JS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, initialization, angular-services

What's the best way to serve the initial JSON data for the models in my angular application with the initial request? (To try and minimize the amount of requests to the server).

Should I just add the data directly into the service on the server, serve and include a seperate file, or is there a more 'angular' way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the nature of the data, and how could it change in the future I think. I prefer to load the data, i.e. for a dropdown list, as an HTTP resource:

```
var myData = [];
$http.get('data/data.json').success(function (data) {
    myData = data;
});
```

This way the data is independent of the code, is loaded asynchronously and you can easily replace the file with an endpoint in the future.

However, I have seen many angular apps in production including the data directly in the controller for optimization, so probably that is the most cost-effective way in terms of request economy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a JS app that needed dynamic localization, which I served with the initial html. The JS creating a window variable was built server-side, and processed by the client when the app was initializing. It was an Ember app, and I was using server side handlebars, but the concept should still be valid. And yes, it is a tiny bit hackish.

Server-side markup:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.localization = {{{json localization}}};
</script>
```

Rendered as

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.localization = {"a-key":"A value"};
</script>
```

In the client:

```
var localization = window.localization;
delete window.localization;
// process localizations
```